# People able to use .php as image extention

Tags: php, html, mysql

As the matter goes, anyone can use any kind of extention aslong as they put .png at the end of the link

http://rsps50.com/logout.php?.png  is what someone is using atm, this causing everyone on my website to logout if they visit homepage.

here was my attempt at stoping it , but did not work :(

```
if (empty($_POST['banner'])) {
  echo '<font color="red">Please add a banner for your server</font><br />';
  $b = FALSE;
} else if (strpos($b, '.php') !== false) {
  echo 'You can only use image extentions';
  $b = 'http://image.com/image.png';
} else {
  $b = strip_tags($_POST['banner']);
}
```

I should note that i do not allow image uploading, i am using a input field and then echo'ing the link

```
<input name="banner" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['banner'])) echo $_POST['banner']; ?>" class="form-control" accept="image/x-png, image/gif, image/jpeg" type="text" placeholder="http://example.com/example.png" required>
```

Any ideas? thanks

Comment: note, you will be fighting a losing battle if you just start trying to list every file extension you don't want.   Also letting people load up any link they want?   You may be inadvertently be turning your site into a spam magnet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using the variable `$b` before assigning a value to it.

So the fourth line should be:

```
} else if (strpos($_POST['banner'], '.php') !== false) {
```

If you want to look for other extensions besides `.php`, you could use a Regex like this:

```
} else if (preg_match("/\.(?:html|php|asp|js)/i", $_POST['banner'])) {
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understood what you need, are you trying to stop people from being logged out when they access something like `http://rsps50.com/logout.php?.png`? Or are you trying to stop people from posting links that contain a link to your websites logout page?

Comment: I've edited, should have been `==`. Try it if what you need is to filter out files with .php extension.

Comment: If you take a look at this page: http://rsps50.com/view/136  and right click the image and get the url for it, notice how they're using logout.php in the image url,

Comment: Didnt work  @marcos   " http://rsps50.com/logout.php?m.png " is what he is using , he could if he wanted to do http://rsps50.com/logout.php?m.png 

And would still let the person add it

Comment: what does the variable $b contains in that case?

Comment: $b = strip_tags($_POST['banner']);

Comment: I mean before the code you posted (before `if (empty($_POST['banner'])) {`)

Comment: I am using javascript aswel, so if theres a way to do it within that, im open to give it a shot, this is my JS for banner field:  


 if (form.banner.value.length < 5) {
 alert( "URL is empty or to short. Must start with http:// and end with .png, .gif, .jpg" );
    form.banner.focus();
    return false ;
  }

Comment: $b is never assigned a value, but you try to use it in your checking `} else if (strpos($b, '.php') !== false) {`. Perhaps what you need is `} else if (strpos($_POST['banner'], '.php') !== false) {`?

Comment: Worked, thank you!  If i wanted to block other extentions say html etc, how would i go about adding that? Would this be correct: 

} else if (strpos($_POST['banner'], '.php','.html','.asp','.js') !== false) {

Comment: Not quite, you could use a regular expression (regex) for that, like this: `} else if (preg_match("/\.(?:html|php|asp|js)/", $_POST['banner'])) {`.